# Markup comment renders different in editor preview

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, editor, markdown-rendering

Have a look at [this revision](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/284108/1). Though it contains the following markup, the third image does not show up in the post:

```
<!-- ![old header] https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKEOa.png)
![new header] https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktnXU.png) -->
![the old and the new header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtGrS.png)
```

However, if you [try to edit it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/284108/edit/3de6f81a-e52a-4efd-9811-9d978c9cbff9), the image will show up in the post. Notice that when you fix the parentheses in the commented-out image links like this:

```
<!-- ![old header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKEOa.png)
![new header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktnXU.png) -->
![the old and the new header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtGrS.png)
```

then the comments break (in preview mode, haven't tested to save). Not sure whether related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see when following your [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/284108/1) again, you'll see that it looks as expected now. This was the same bug as [Remote parser fails to parse image in my post but javascript parser (during edit) parses it OK](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251000/remote-parser-fails-to-parse-image-in-my-post-but-javascript-parser-during-edit) which I fixed a few months ago.